# How to properly mock an Eloquent model method in Laravel for testing?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to write a test for a Laravel controller where I want to mock a method of an Eloquent model. I have a LoginController that uses the User model, and I want to mock the getRoleNames method of the User model to test the controller's behavior.

I've tried using Mockery to create a mock of the User model and bind it to the service container. However, I keep getting null when calling the mocked method.

Assuming you have correctly set up the User model with the HasRoles trait, and you want to mock the getRoleNames method provided by Spatie, you can still use the previous approach with Mockery. The key is to ensure that you're mocking the correct method based on the Spatie Laravel Permissions documentation.
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage#content-get-permissions-for-a-user

```
public function createUser(array $attributes = [])
{
   return User::factory()->create($attributes);
}
```

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
  ...

  public function roles()
  {
    return auth()->user()->getRoleNames();
  }
}
```

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
 ...

 use HasRoles;

}
```

```
trait HasRoles {
 ...

    public function getRoleNames(): Collection
    {
        $this->loadMissing('roles');

        return $this->roles->pluck('name');
    }

}
```

```
test('roles()', function () {
    $user = $this->createUser();
    $this->actingAs($user);

    $userMock = Mockery::mock(User::class);

    $userMock->expects($this->once())
        ->shouldReceive('getRoleNames')
        ->andReturn(new Collection(['role1', 'role2']));

    $this->app->instance(User::class, $userMock);

    $controller = new LoginController();

    $roles = $controller->roles();
    dd($roles);
});
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and how I can properly mock the getRoleNames method of the User model in my test to make it return the mocked roles.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/25819628/7155723

Comment: No, no, no, and more no. I have seen these types of questions so many times. Do not mock an Eloquent model EVER. There are a lot of things going on behind the scenes that you would truly have to mock a lot of things, if you later add a scope or anything similar, you should also maybe mock that, and more. So, to answer your question, you have to NOT mock the model(s) but use factories to have the stuff that you expect. As simple as that. Check my SO profile, I have links about that there. To make your life easier, just use factories and set what you expect to have, NEVER mock an eloquent model

Comment: I also now saw that you are literally instantiating the controller and calling a method. This is not "bad", but you should be doing a feature test, literally using `$this->post` or `$this->get` or whatever, do a request, do not instantiate the controller...